# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file - Beginner working with multiple files

Tags: python, file-io

I am just learning python (2.7) and am making a simple text maze game with multiple levels on different files:

```
try: #this one works perfectly, it runs the file until it quits with quit()
  execfile("....Lockdown.py")
except SystemExit:
  print "Next Level"

try: #this one doesn't work even though it is almost perfectly identical with Lockdown
  execfile("....Lockdown2.py")
except SystemExit:
  print "Next Level"

#other levels
```

When it runs Lockdown2.py I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File LockdownGame.py ...
  #-> until execfile("....Lockdown2.py")
  File "...Lockdown2.py", line 708, in available  #available is another function
decide(raw_input("Where do you decide to head? "))

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Lockdown2 (and Lockdown) works like this

```
#the building of the maze
def available(): #checks where the user can walk
    #looks through the entire maze to look at where the user is standing, where his back is and if there are walls in that direction
    #makes sure the user isn't facing
    print "You can walk %s." % (can_walk[0]) #cutting out how it tells this
    decide(raw_input("What direction do you decide to head? "))

def decide(dec):
    if dec == "left": #and the other three directions, 
        #edits the maze and their surrounding to their new location
   else:
      print "(Write your option as it's written)"
      decide(raw_input("What direction do you decide to head? "))

available()
```

It crashes after putting up the `raw_input`, even though it is virtually identical code to Lockdown, and it doesn't error in prints before this, or when this raw_input is in Lockdown.

Comment: When you say 'virtually identical' - what are the changes between the two files?  Have you tried running Lockdown twice, to confirm the issue is in the script above, and not in Lockdown2?

Comment: Virtually identical as in, the base code is the same, just changed some variable names and the variables of where you can walk. When running Lockdown twice, i get the same error as in Lockdown2; it has the error appear after the raw_input is asked.

Comment: Ok, so can you paste the code where raw_input appears?  We can't help debug if we can't see what's happening...

Comment: I was cleaning up the code a bit, i changed it from quit() to sys.exit() and it works perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 0):

**Change quit() to sys.exit()**, it will completely close off Lockdown before initiating Lockdown2

Comment: Can you at least post the relevant code in your question, otherwise it's incomplete, and not of much use to anyone else.